# VirtualBox stuck on saving state at 100% - what to do?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, freeze

My VM running 32bit Ubuntu 16.04 was doing just fine since...well, now. The host is 64bit Win 10.

Upon closing of my VM every day I always do two things - commit my code and then also save the state of the machine. Sadly I forgot to do the first and as it seems I'm screwed with the second.

VirtualBox current shows me the "Saving state" dialog window for my VM and the progressbar is full plus the percentage shows 100%. It's been like this for 15 minutes.

As the title clearly states I have no idea what to do in this situation since - for using VirtualBox for almost a decade - I have never ever experienced this.

Process explorer shows me that the process is not dead yet the dialog window doesn't seem to be responsive.

Inside the snapshots folder for my VM I can see 4 files with strange names. Two of the files are for my fresh installation snapshot, which I always make once I install the OS inside the VM in case I need a complete reset of the VM's state. The other two are from today evening, shortly before this issue occurred.

What can I do to save my work? Yes, my fault I forgot to commit it but telling me this doesn't help at all.

I've checked [this bug report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7756), which is 7 years old yet has been recently (4 weeks ago) updated and labeled as critical. I was unable to find any solution there or elsewhere.

Just in case I made a copy of all the 4 files inside my snapshot folder.

Comment: I have the same issue on 6.0.16 r135674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky me, it seems that indeed the state was saved and only the UI was stuck (even though the process was still running before I terminated it). Basically what I have found online is that in most cases the HDD is not corrupted but instead the VM's profile might, which is not a problem since this is something that can be recreated without too much of a fuss.

Comment: This was not the case for me. VirtualBox is such a piece of garbage.

Comment: Had the same problem with Win10 host and Win7 guest, the state was not saved and had to do a clean boot losing unsaved data. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I had actually reinstalled Virtualbox guest additions in that session, it suggested to reboot and instead I saved the state